# Creating sorted CSV files in Excel with macro's (imported from OTRS)

Tags: excel, vba, csv, otrs

I want to make an easy one-click button in Excel 2010

- to open the .csv files from OTRS.
- Sort the semicolon delimiters
- 2 columns have to be sorted.

The csv format looks like this:

```
"Ticketnummer";"Leeftijd";"Aangemaakt";"Gesloten";"FirstLock"
```

I've tried a macro. This is almost right. I would like to have a dialogue box in which I can choose the .csv file instead of a specified filename in the code.

The macro version with fixed filename looks like this:

```html
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\outbound.csv", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "OTRS WV outbound"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("C1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("I1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

How can i change this macro so the first step after running the macro is the open file dialogue box?

Comment: using google search for vba dialgog box and it gives you this url which has your answer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839409(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Hello @Sorceri, Thank you for your reply. Could you help me how to ad these lines to the macro i am using? My macro/vba skills are like zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you would allow yourself to pick the csv file

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Dim dlgResult
Dim ofd As FileDialog
Set ofd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With ofd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Clear
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Add filter to show only csv files
    .Filters.Add "CSV files", "*.csv", 1
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        dlgResult = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "You must select a file."
    Exit Sub
End If
End With
dlgResult = "TEXT;" & dlgResult
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        dlgResult, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "OTRS WV outbound"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("C1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("I1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Lempke it will create an error if they click cancel.  I updated the code with error handling for that.

Comment: Some colleagues will click away the dialog box. Is it possible that this code does not  create an error (runtime #5, ) when canceling the dialog box